# python Tkinter, Queue, Threading, gives out of stack space error

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, queue

I am trying to connect raw_input() to a Tkinter gui, by using Queus and Threading. Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter
import time
import threading
import Queue

class UI(Tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, queue=None):
        self.queue = queue
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title("what does console say")
        self.master.minsize(40, 30)
        swd = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        fwd = 320
        fht = 240
        self.master.geometry('{0:d}x{1:d}+{2:d}+{3:d}'.format(
                fwd, fht, swd - fwd, 0))

        self.message = Tkinter.StringVar()
        mesgbox = Tkinter.Label(master, textvariable=self.message)
        mesgbox.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.pack()
        self.processqueue()

    def processqueue(self):
        try:
            message = '\n'.join([self.message.get(),
                                 self.queue.get_nowait()])
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            self.message.set(message)
        self.master.after(100, self.processqueue)


class ThreadedTask(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = 1
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            message = raw_input('put some words:')
            self.queue.put("[Message] {0:s}".format(message))

queue = Queue.Queue()
gui = UI(queue=queue)
job = ThreadedTask(queue)
job.start()
gui.mainloop()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error in background error handler:
out of stack space (infinite loop?)
    while executing
"::tcl::Bgerror {out of stack space (infinite loop?)} {-code 1 -level 0 -errorcode NONE -errorinfo {out of stack space (infinite loop?)
    ("after" sc..."
```

Could anyone help me with it? Thank you in advance!

Another thing is that, this code works if I do not use the raw_input(), but some machine generated text, i.e.:

```
    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.queue.put("[Message] {0:d}".format(i))
```

Could anyone explain why?

Comment: It works as expected for me.....

Comment: What machine are you at? Mine is Fedora 18, python 2.7.3.
I have searched around, and found that this could be the result of tk not being compiled with enable-threading. However, I am just wondering why the exception only raise when I use raw_input().

Comment: I'm on windows 32-bit, python 2.7.3, tk 8.5 BTW I don't think that's the cause of the error cause otherwise it wouldn't work at all for you however I'm not sure though...

Comment: Why would you use raw_input in a GUI? Depending on how you start the GUI, there may not be any way for the user to enter data. The whole point of a GUI is to create a window for the user to interact with?

Comment: The situation is that I have a console based program already, and I want to combine this with another noisy console based program, which I wish I can put the output to a gui message box. The first program has some raw_input feature, therefore I am testing if I could make the given code work here.

Comment: I agree that I could put all interactive stuff into GUI. But I thought that gonna need more work than just a quick add-on.

Answer (score 0):

After a deep searching, I found this post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817554/obscure-repeatable-crashes-in-multi-threaded-python-console-application-using-t)

I am not sure if this is exactly the problem, but it inspired me, in the way that I reformed my code, by putting the gui mainloop() in a second thread.

In this way, it works like a charm, although I still don't exactly why there is such behaviour.