# Show what the server is doing in tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to python and I am having trouble showing the command line output of my server in a tkinter textbox. I want to show what is happening in a tkinter textbox and show the list of IP addresses in the listbox. I have looked at books but am having trouble getting this to work. I am using python 3.5.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import socket
import time
import sys

from queue import Queue
import struct
import signal

NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2
JOB_NUMBER = [1, 2]
queue = Queue()

COMMANDS = {'help':['Shows this help'],
            'list':['Lists connected clients'],
            'select':['Selects a client by its index. Takes index as a parameter'],
            'quit':['Stops current connection with a client. To be used when client is selected'],
            'shutdown':['Shuts server down'],
           }


class MultiServer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.host = ''
        self.port = 9999
        self.socket = None
        self.all_connections = []
        self.all_addresses = []

    def print_help(self):
        for cmd, v in COMMANDS.items():
            # print("{0}:\t{1}".format(cmd, v[0]))
            self.textBox.insert("{0}:\t{1}".format(cmd, v[0]))
        return

    def register_signal_handler(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.quit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.quit_gracefully)
        return

    def quit_gracefully(self, signal=None, frame=None):
        print('\nQuitting gracefully')
        for conn in self.all_connections:
            try:
                conn.shutdown(2)
                conn.close()
            except Exception as e:
                print('Could not close connection %s' % str(e))
                # continue
        self.socket.close()
        sys.exit(0)

    def socket_create(self):
        try:
            self.socket = socket.socket()
        except socket.error as msg:
            print("Socket creation error: " + str(msg))
            # TODO: Added exit
            sys.exit(1)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        return

    def socket_bind(self):
        """ Bind socket to port and wait for connection from client """
        try:
            self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
            self.socket.listen(5)
        except socket.error as e:
            print("Socket binding error: " + str(e))
            time.sleep(5)
            self.socket_bind()
        return

    def accept_connections(self):
        """ Accept connections from multiple clients and save to list """
        for c in self.all_connections:
            c.close()
        self.all_connections = []
        self.all_addresses = []
        while 1:
            try:
                conn, address = self.socket.accept()
                conn.setblocking(1)
                client_hostname = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                address = address + (client_hostname,)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error accepting connections: %s' % str(e))
                # Loop indefinitely
                continue
            self.all_connections.append(conn)
            self.all_addresses.append(address)
            print('\nConnection has been established: {0} ({1})'.format(address[-1], address[0]))
        return

    def start_turtle(self):
        """ Interactive prompt for sending commands remotely """
        while True:
            cmd = input('turtle> ')
            if cmd == 'list':
                self.list_connections()
                continue
            elif 'select' in cmd:
                target, conn = self.get_target(cmd)
                if conn is not None:
                    self.send_target_commands(target, conn)
            elif cmd == 'shutdown':
                    queue.task_done()
                    queue.task_done()
                    print('Server shutdown')
                    break
                    # self.quit_gracefully()
            elif cmd == 'help':
                self.print_help()
            elif cmd == '':
                pass
            else:
                print('Command not recognized')
        return

    def list_connections(self):
        """ List all connections """
        results = ''
        for i, conn in enumerate(self.all_connections):
            try:
                conn.send(str.encode(' '))
                conn.recv(20480)
            except:
                del self.all_connections[i]
                del self.all_addresses[i]
                continue
            results += str(i) + '   ' + str(self.all_addresses[i][0]) + '   ' + str(
                self.all_addresses[i][1]) + '   ' + str(self.all_addresses[i][2]) + '\n'
        print('----- Clients -----' + '\n' + results)
        return

    def get_target(self, cmd):
        """ Select target client
        :param cmd:
        """
        target = cmd.split(' ')[-1]
        try:
            target = int(target)
        except:
            print('Client index should be an integer')
            return None, None
        try:
            conn = self.all_connections[target]
        except IndexError:
            print('Not a valid selection')
            return None, None
        print("You are now connected to " + str(self.all_addresses[target][2]))
        return target, conn

    def read_command_output(self, conn):
        """ Read message length and unpack it into an integer
        :param conn:
        """
        raw_msglen = self.recvall(conn, 4)
        if not raw_msglen:
            return None
        msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
        # Read the message data
        return self.recvall(conn, msglen)

    def recvall(self, conn, n):
        """ Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
        :param n:
        :param conn:
        """
        # TODO: this can be a static method
        data = b''
        while len(data) < n:
            packet = conn.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data += packet
        return data

    def send_target_commands(self, target, conn):
        """ Connect with remote target client
        :param conn:
        :param target:
        """
        conn.send(str.encode(" "))
        cwd_bytes = self.read_command_output(conn)
        cwd = str(cwd_bytes, "utf-8")
        print(cwd, end="")
        while True:
            try:
                cmd = input()
                if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
                    conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
                    cmd_output = self.read_command_output(conn)
                    client_response = str(cmd_output, "utf-8")
                    print(client_response, end="")
                if cmd == 'quit':
                    break
            except Exception as e:
                print("Connection was lost %s" %str(e))
                break
        del self.all_connections[target]
        del self.all_addresses[target]
        return


def create_workers():
    """ Create worker threads (will die when main exits) """
    server = MultiServer()
    server.register_signal_handler()
    for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(server,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    return


def work(server):
    """ Do the next job in the queue (thread for handling connections, another for sending commands)
    :param server:
    """
    while True:
        x = queue.get()
        if x == 1:
            server.socket_create()
            server.socket_bind()
            server.accept_connections()
        if x == 2:
            server.start_turtle()
        queue.task_done()
    return

def create_jobs():
    """ Each list item is a new job """
    for x in JOB_NUMBER:
        queue.put(x)
    queue.join()
    return

def main():
    create_workers()
    create_jobs()



class App(threading.Thread, MultiServer):

    def __init__(self):
        MultiServer.__init__(self)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()


    def run(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        # create all of the main containers
        self.top_frame = Frame()
        self.center_frame = Frame()

        # layout all of the main containers
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky='NSEW')
        self.center_frame.grid(row=1, pady=5, sticky='NSEW')

        # Top frame
        self.logo = Label(self.top_frame, text='SunGroup')
        self.logo.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

        self.command = Entry(self.top_frame, width=25)
        self.command.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)

        self.addButton = Button(self.top_frame, text='Enter', width=5)
        self.addButton.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)

        self.listButton = Button(self.top_frame, text='List', width=5, command=self.list_connections)
        self.listButton.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.selectButton = Button(self.top_frame, text='Select', width=5, command=self.get_target)
        self.selectButton.grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.quitButton = Button(self.top_frame, text='Quit', width=5, command=self.quit_gracefully)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=1, column=4)

        self.helpButton = Button(self.top_frame, text='Help', width=5, command=self.print_help)
        self.helpButton.grid(row=1, column=5)


        # Center frame
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.center_frame, width=20, height=20)
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)

        self.textBox = Text(self.center_frame, width=35, height=20)
        self.textBox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
        self.textBox.insert(END, self.start_turtle, self.print_help)


        self.root.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    main()
```

Comment: SO is not a personal debugging service, try to post a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of posing all your code. Just post the minimal amount needed to deal with your specific problem. All you should need is the tk window, a text box, and maybe a button and an entry box. The rest is just in the way. After that give some example of what you have tried and we can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get:

```
turtle> Tcl_WaitForEvent: Notifier not initialized
Abort
```

and Python quits.  If that's your issue too, then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15817555/5771269) discusses an issue with calling `input()` outside of the main thread when Tk is active which generates this very error.  The work around seems to be instead of:

```
cmd = input('turtle> ')
```

do something like:

```
print('turtle>', end=' ')
sys.stdout.flush()
cmd = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
```

This gets further, but I can't say things then run smoothly.  Does your client/server code work without Tk?  When I try it with Tk, or stripping out Tk completely, it seems to hang when I do a ***list*** if there's an active client conection.  When I quit my client it recovers.  This may be an artifact of how I'm testing but it's essential that your code bascially works before trying to layer an interface atop it.